# setting the Verbosity only for few /sequences/objects/interfaces in uvm?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

How do I control the verbosity of certain components so that I can set a verbosity to only few of the components?

Lets say, for example in the verification of a particular feature, the test, few set of components/sequences/objects/interfaces etc are involved. I would like to set the verbosity of only these to be `UVM_HIGH`. I do not want to set the global severity to be set `UVM_HIGH` since lot of unrelated debug messages could come in which might increase the log size.

What would be a cleaner way of doing this? Its okay to use an additional commandline-plusarg for triggering this. Basically, the requirement would be that the test/components/sequences/objects/interfaces involved for a particular feature verification should take the global severity or the feature specific severity depending on which is higher.

Please note that one cannot use the built in report methods of `uvm_component` since, the `uvm_info` statements can be inside `uvm_object` extended classes as well as interfaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control the verbosity of a component from command line as a simulation argument. There are two choices:

- `+uvm_set_verbosity=<comp>,<id>,<verbosity>,<phase>`
- `+uvm_set_verbosity=<comp>,<id>,<verbosity>,time,<phase>` This one lets you specify the simulation time you want the applied verbosity to start

`comp` is the path of the component and wildcard `*` is supported. Example: `uvm_test_top.env.agnt.*`
`id` is the message identifier. you can apply to all messages within the component scope with by setting the id to `_ALL_`
`verbosity` is verbosity e.g. `UVM_LOW`, `UVM_MEDIUM`, `UVM_HIGH`, etc.
`phase` is phase you want the verbosity to be applied to.

For more detail i suggest reading:

- The [UVM reference manual](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.2/html/index.html) section on [Command Line Processor](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.2/html/files/base/uvm_cmdline_processor-svh.html#uvm_cmdline_processor.Built-in_UVM_Aware_Command_Line_Arguments)
- [UVM Message Display Commands Capabilities, Proper Usage and Guidelines](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2014AUS_UVM_Messages.pdf) by Clifford E. Cummings

Comment: If you are like me and you have a script that runs your sims for you the wildcard on the command line might cause a problem. This just requires that you escape it with a backslash`\*`

Comment: Thanks Greg, 
but this would require one to keep track of all the components that take part in a feature verification and use the plusarg for each of the component. I was wondering is there a way to solve this with a single plusarg. I wouldn't mind adding extra lines of code in to my TB

Comment: @VineethVS , Read 4.2. _Changing verbosity using method calls_ from [UVM Message Display Commands Capabilities](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2014AUS_UVM_Messages.pdf) to see how to set the verbosity from within code. I didn't include it in my original answer because it can create maintenance mess if you code only to solve a handful situations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `uvm_report_catcher` for this. It works with `uvm_object` and interface. You can also use `get_id()`, `get_message()` etc. API for matching particular component/object and can only set verbosity of that component/object.

check my simple example on [here on edaplaygroud](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Z_P)

Answer (score 1):

I tried different ways and also came up with this way.

Not sure how much it would be helpful for people.

simulate this with run time commands `+user_verb=UVM_LOW +UVM_VERBOSITY=UVM_MEDIUM`

```
class user_class extends uvm_object;

  string report_id = "user_class";
  string user_verb;

  typedef uvm_enum_wrapper#(uvm_verbosity)  uvm_verbosity_wrapper_e;

  uvm_verbosity current_verb;
  uvm_verbosity USER_VERBOSITY=UVM_HIGH;

  function new (string name="my_class");
    super.new(name);
    report_id = name;
    //void'($value$plusargs("user_verb=%s",user_verb));
    //void'(uvm_verbosity_wrapper_e::from_name (user_verb,USER_VERBOSITY));
    if ($test$plusargs("user_verb")) begin
      current_verb=uvm_top.get_report_verbosity_level(UVM_INFO,"current_verb");           USER_VERBOSITY=uvm_top.get_report_verbosity_level(UVM_INFO,"user_verb");
    end

    $display("user_verb = %s",user_verb); 
    $display("current_verb = %s",current_verb); 
  endfunction : new


  task display;
    `uvm_info(report_id,"This is my message",USER_VERBOSITY)    
  endtask

endclass: user_class


module top;
  string id;
  string report_id = "top";
  user_class m_user_class;

  initial begin
    m_user_class = new("m_user_class");
    m_user_class.display;
    `uvm_info(report_id,"This is my message",UVM_LOW)
  end
endmodule: top
```

A working example can be found at edaplayground [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/6_Vt)